# How to check if a view controller is of type UIHostingController

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui, uihostingcontroller

i have a UIHostingController that is hosting a SwiftUI view called CatalogView.
when showing it, an environment object is attached, so basically from UIKit it is shown like this:

```
let rootCatalogView = CatalogView()

let appState = AppState.get()
let catalogView = UIHostingController(rootView: rootCatalogView.environmentObject(appState))

navigationController.pushViewController(catalogView, animated: true)
```

now at a later time i need to check if this UIHostingController is in the list of navigationController.viewControllers

the type(of:) is showing the following, which kind of make sense:

```
UIHostingController<ModifiedContent<CatalogView, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<AppState>>>>
```

things like vc.self is UIHostingController.Type or vc.self is UIHostingController< CatalogView >.Type both return false (vc is an element of navigationController.viewControllers

the following obviously works, it returns true, but any change in the initialisation of the UIHostingController will change its type

```
vc.isKind(of: UIHostingController<ModifiedContent<CatalogView, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<StoreManager>>>>.self)
```

how can i check if the view controller is of type UIHostingController?
or at least how can i cast the controller to UIHostingController so that i can check its rootview?

Comment: Try `if vc is UIHostingController`

Comment: UIHostingController is a class with generic parameter, so that does not work.

Comment: xcode gives the following error: Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred in cast to 'UIHostingController'

Comment: Can you make `catalogView` a property and then check something like `if navigationController.viewControllers.contains(catalogView) { ... }` ?  (typed in  browser, not tested in Xcode).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the generic parameter, we cannot cast the ViewController to find if it is a `UIHostingController` without knowing the full constraint.

### **I should note that this it not an ideal fix and it is really just a work around.**

`UIHostingController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` so we could do the following.

Create a computed property on `UIViewController` that returns the name of the class that is used to create `UIViewController`. This gives us something to search for in the list of `ViewControllers` contained in the `UINavigationController`

```
extension UIViewController {
    var className: String {
        String(describing: Self.self)
    }
}
```

Create a few UIViewController subclasses and our UIHostingController

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {}
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {}
class MyHostingController<Content>: UIHostingController<Content> where Content : View {}

let first = FirstViewController()
let second = SecondViewController()
let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: Text("I'm in a hosting controller"))
let myHosting = MyHostingController(rootView: Text("My hosting vc"))
```

We can then add these to a `UINavigationController`.

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: first)
nav.pushViewController(second, animated: false)
nav.pushViewController(hosting, animated: false)
nav.pushViewController(myHosting, animated: false)
```

Now that we have some ViewControllers inside our UINavigationController we can now iterate across them and find a ViewController that has a className that contains what we are looking for.

```
for vc in nav.viewControllers {
    print(vc.className)
}
```

This would print the following to the console:

> FirstViewController
>
> SecondViewController
>
> UIHostingController<Text>
>
> MyHostingController<Text>

You can then `for-where` to find the ViewController in the hierarchy.

```
for vc in nav.viewControllers where vc.className.contains("UIHostingController") {
    // code that should run if its class is UIHostingController
    print(vc.className)
}

for vc in nav.viewControllers where vc.className.contains("MyHostingController") {
    // code that should run if its class is MyHostingController
    print(vc.className)
}
```

As I said above, this is not an ideal solution but it may help you until there is a a better way of casting without knowing the generic constraint.

Comment: this looks like a viable solution. thanks

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can't cast to generic class, but **you can declare protocol** and implement it only for UIHostingViewController

```swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

private protocol AnyUIHostingViewController: AnyObject {}
extension UIHostingController: AnyUIHostingViewController {}

extension UIViewController {
   var isHosting: Bool { self is AnyUIHostingViewController } 
}
```

and somewhere in your code

```swift
func someFunction(viewController: UIViewController) {
  if viewController.isHosting {
     print("That is hosting view controller")
  }
}
```

Comment: This should definitely be an accepted answer. Thanks!